# unreal engine 4 : Macos version is very laggy

Tags: unreal-engine4

I use unreal 4. I don't know if this is the problem with macos version of something wrong with my specs. I use macbook pro 16, Intel i9 8core 2.3 ghz, RAM 16Gb, VGA AMD Radeon pro 5500M. It's laggy and slow. If i click a button seems that i can feel tiny bit of delay.

It took about 25sec to load empty vr project.

Everytime i start unreal, it always do 'compiling shaders..' which always make my whole system slow. is this normal? compiling will run everytime i start unreal engine and took more than 1 minutes to finish.

I only have 1 test project in unreal folder , it's just simply empty project.

Anyone mac users and have the same problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Same symptoms - did you figure out a workaround? Or did you choose Unity or Godot instead? Would love to know what you ended up with

Comment: So far i've been playing with unity. Much better for me in mac compared UE.